# Using addLayer and setVisible in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I've a doubt about use of `addLayer` and `setVisible`. I've a sidebar with a checkbox for add or remove some layers.

For example, I have **LayerA** and **LayerB**, when I click on LayerA on the sidebar is activated this code:

```
map.addLayer(LayerA);
LayerA.setVisible(true);
map.removeLayer(LayerB);
```

And vice versa if I click on LayerB.

Is it correct use both `addLayer` and `setVisible`?

Comment: Why would you want to set removed layer visibility to false? It does no harm, but doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Yes `LayerB.setVisible(false);` it is a my error. Is it a right way use `setVisible(true)` when it is used `addLayer`?

Comment: Again, layer is by default visible, unless set otherwise by `.setVisible(false)`. There is no harm in explicitly setting visible layer to be visible by `.setVisible(true)`, but it's definitely not necessary.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Can you add this answer into the section belove?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When layer is added to the map by `map.addLayer(layer)` method, it's by default made visible, and when it's removed from the map by `map.removeLayer(layer)` method, it's by default not visible.

There is no harm in setting already visible layer to be visible with `layer.setVisible(true)` call, or setting removed layer to not be visible with `layer.setVisible(false)` call, but it's definitely not necessary.

But, if you remove layer from the map and also set it to not be visible, when you later add it to the map, it won't be visible automatically, you have to explicitly set it to be visible.